# Twitter TypeAhead.js not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, typeahead

I am using Twitter TypeAhead.js plugin [here](http://plugins.upbootstrap.com/bootstrap-ajax-typeahead/),
my ajax response looks like that

```
[{"id":1,"value":"EG","text":"Egypt","tokens":["EG","Egypt"]}]
```

My jQuery code is

```
     $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
            ajax: {
               url: "<?=base_url("/main/search")?>" ,
               method: "get"
            }
        });
```

When I type anything in the input, the ajax request is sent successfully, but I got nothing appearing into my typeahead list! Any ideas?

Comment: typeahead.js is not part of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

The source property for your typeahead call is the .ajax post.  Since you aren't defining a source, there is no way access your returned data.

Here is a good sample for you to reference. http://developer-paradize.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-use-bootstrap-typeahead-with.html

Comment: I tried to use the source property but I got this error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined bootstrap-typeahead.js:284)

Comment: You need to wrap the ajax call in a function.  Please look at the sample I posted for you.

Comment: I  looked at it , and updated my code to be exactly the same but still getting (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined bootstrap-typeahead.js:284) even before the request is sent , whenever I Change the input's value i got this error added to my console!